# SQL Error (unknown column in having clause).

Tags: mysql, sql

```
[SQL]SELECT
vlog.lead_id, vlog.phone_number
FROM
vicidial_log as vlog
GROUP BY vlog.lead_id
HAVING(
CASE 
WHEN vlog.status = 'NA' THEN 1 
WHEN vlog.status = 'ADC' THEN 1 
END
) = COUNT(*)

[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'vlog.status' in 'having clause'
```

The query above is not working. I am trying to achieve this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ej4fM8GptBk9FvGJC8AkUH/0 in sense.

```
 [SQL]SELECT
    vlog.lead_id, vlog.phone_number, vlog.status
    FROM
    vicidial_log as vlog
    GROUP BY vlog.lead_id
    HAVING(
    CASE 
    WHEN vlog.status = 'NA' THEN 1 
    WHEN vlog.status = 'ADC' THEN 1 
    END
    ) = COUNT(*)
```

THIS WORKS BUT IT DOESN'T GIVE ME THE RESULTS I WANT

status = can be anything
lead_id = not unique
phone_number = not unique

I am trying to find phone numbers WHERE atleast the status is either

```
ADC
NA
OR BOTH ADC AND NA
```

Any other combination should not return the phone number.

Comment: Data in DB fiddle doesn't correspond to what you are talking about...

Comment: You left out the `count` aggregate from the `having` clause. `mysql` allows this syntax in your 2nd example, but could return misleading results.  It should be `having count(case...` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's shot in the dark, but maybe it will work for you. Change your `HAVING` clause to:

```
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN vlog.status in ('NA','ADC') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = COUNT(*)
```

Comment: According to his description this is correct answer, if lead_id has both `ADC` and `NA` and no other status then `count(*)` would be 2 and `sum(..)` will also return 2 same goes for if `lead_id` has only one status which either `ADC` or `NA` the count and sum will be 1 which again meets the criteria

Comment: How can I implement the query so that atleast 10 records exist

Comment: It depends on data you have :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this would work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT lead_id, phone_number
FROM vicidial_log vlog
WHERE status IN ('NA', 'ADC')
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM vicidial_log vlog2
                WHERE status NOT IN ('NA','ADC')
                AND vlog.lead_id = vlog2.lead_id
                AND vlog.phone_number = vlog2.phone_number)
```

It's not 100% clear whether you need the comparison to be on both `lead_id` and `phone_number` though.